# Creating a sorting method in Linked List class without using array. C#

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to create a sorting method that will sort according alphabetical order of name. I can't use any array of any sort at all.
Any help would be appreciated.

SortByCustomerName():  This method will sort the linked list by the customer name in ascending order.

```
class LinkedList
{
    private Node head;  // first node in the linked list
    private int count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set { count = value; }
    }

    public Node Head
    {
        get { return head; }
    }
    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;    // creates an empty linked list
        count = 0;
    }

    public void AddFront(int n)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(n);
        newNode.Link = head;
        head = newNode;
        count++;

    }
    public void DeleteFront()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            Node temp = head;
            head = temp.Link;
            temp = null;
            count--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. What's your problem?

Comment: How do I add a sorting method into the current linked list class? And what is the logic behind a sorting method with using an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for this, which does not require random access/ an array. Here's an [example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/) (it's in C, but should be easily transferable).